# An error occurred while updating the entries

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm strugglish with adding feature for my controller. While adding new item, receving the error like: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
I debugged it, and understood ProductDetailIs is null and here is the issue. But, can not figure out how to mend the problem.

Here is the DTO models:

```
public class WishlistItemDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string CustomerId { get; set; }

        public ProductDetailsDtoWithPrimaryImage ProductDetails { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

public class WishListItemCreationDto
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }

        public int ProductDetailId { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(WishListItemCreationDto wishListItemDto)
{
    var itemAdd = _mapper.Map<WishlistItemDto>(wishListItemDto);
    var itemCreated = await _wishListItemService.AddAsync(itemAdd);

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetId), new { id = itemCreated.Id }, wishListItemDto);
}
```

Service:

```
public async Task<WishlistItemDto> AddAsync(WishlistItemDto item)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<WishlistItem>(item);
    await _wishListItemRepository.AddAsync(entity);

    return _mapper.Map<WishlistItemDto>(entity);
}
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<WishlistItem> AddAsync(WishlistItem item)
{
    await _context.Set<WishlistItem>().AddAsync(item);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return item;
}
```

Comment: Hello @dotnetlooper and welcome to Stack Overflow. the first step would be to create a *minimal* example in order to isolate the problem. In your case, it would be to remove `_mapper_` and Repository (not sure what its purpose anyway) from the picture. It *seems* that the problem has little to do with entity framework - but we won't know until you simplify the question. Please refer to this link for further guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here:

```
var itemAdd = _mapper.Map<WishlistItemDto>(wishListItemDto);
```

your "wishListItemDto" is passed in as a 'WishListItemCreationDto' which contains only a ProductDetailsId. Automapper will have no way of knowing how to convert that into a `ProductDetailsDtoWithPrimaryImage`.

Typically for something like this where you pass an reference ID you would compose your entity by either populating a FK or loading the referenced entity. Your existing service and repository patterns will complicate your final solution. From what I can see from your example I'd look at creating an `AddAsync` method that accepts the `WishListItemCreationDto`:

```
public async Task<WishlistItemCreationDto> AddAsync(WishlistItemCreationDto item)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<WishlistItem>(item);
    var productDetails = _productDetailsRepository.GetById(item.ProductDetailsId);
    entity.ProductDetails = productDetails;
    await _wishListItemRepository.AddAsync(entity);

    return _mapper.Map<WishlistItemDto>(entity);
}
```

Without the added abstraction complexity of the Service and Repository the add operation can be a whole lot simpler:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(WishListItemCreationDto wishListItemDto)
{
    // or better, use an injected dependency to the Context...
    // TODO: add applicable exception handling.
    using(var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var item = _mapper.Map<WishlistItem>(wishListItemDto);
        var productDetails = context.ProductDetails.Single(x => x.ProductDetailsId == wishListItemDto.ProductDetailsId);
        item.ProductDetails = productDetails;
        context.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetId), new { id = itemCreated.Id }, wishListItemDto);
    }
}
```